# CSS file is applying on another react component even without importing

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I'm using React to build a website and I want to use .CSS files for my CSS and I'm using import './example.css' in my component file.
Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'Home.css';
const Home = () => {
return (
<div className="example">
          Hi
</div>
)
}
```

and if i create another page but don't import this CSS file, I get the styles on my other page
other page:

```
import React from 'react';

const About= () => {
return (
<div className="example">
          Hi
</div>
)
}
```

Any reason and solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When importing a css file like you've done it will be injected into the project and not just into the component you're importing it from.

What you're looking for is [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) ([adding css-modules using create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/))

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from 'Home.css';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.example}>
          Hi
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can I use same className in all files with css module?

Comment: yes. because css-module will rename the classname to something like `example_dfd23` for it to be unique in the browser.

Comment: What if i want to concatenate another class with this css module. Let's say, a bootstrap class. Would i just use template strings like `className={row ${styles.example}}`

Comment: @IbrahimFarooq there is several ways of doing this. one is what you suggested. another is `className={["row", styles.example].join(" ")}` and then there's a helper package for this called [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Comment: @Philip I believe even with css modules styles applied to html elements for eg - h1 { color: red } , will still be global and applied to all components? Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using the same class in both of your components.
Doing `import 'Home.css'` does not encapsulate `.css` only for that component, all of the `.css` gets bundled together so it ends up overwriting styles somewhere down the line.

For each of the components, you can specify a unique `className` on top of your component, and use that class to style only that component.
`.home-container .header { ... }`
You can also make one global `.css` part to put styles that you want to keep using throughout the whole app.